# How to know if a linq Queryable has any predicate Where?

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable, predicate

I need a method to check if my `Queryable` has any predicate `Where`.

```
var queryA = db.Contacts.Where(x => x.IsAdministrator);

var hasPredicate = HasPredicate(queryA);
// return true

var queryB = db.Contacts;

var hasPredicateB = HasPredicate(queryB);
// return false
```

I know this is not the best approach, and obviously you all agree.

I'll explain quickly and superficially:

I have a method that returns a query that will call QueryBase which I use as primary research in another context.

In the present context I need the list of QueryBase IDs to make a Join.

Anyway here we go, the objects used in these studies are very large and complex, so do not want to "redo" the QueryBase. When this huge object has no criterion, and the query is "raw".

I know, I should validate if the object is empty, but that would really work, because there are several different default values, which vary according to other values, and all these validations occur within the method that returns the QueryBase.

I just need skip this if the query is "empty".

Comment: Conceptually - doing this seems like a bad approach. What is the bigger thing you're trying to do?

Comment: You can find out whether you're working with a `DbSet` or not by just checking `queryB is DbSet` or `(queryB as DbSet) == null`, but I presume that's not powerful enough for you. What is your use case?

Comment: Not to put words in the OP's mouth, but the ability to figure out if a query has a where clause would be extremely useful if he's writing a Linq provider.

Comment: @KeithS: If the OP is writing a LINQ provider, this isn't the right place to start.

Answer (score 4):

You *could* use the [`IQueryable.Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.expression.aspx) property, and see whether that includes a call to `Queryable.Where`. However, this feels like a very brittle approach in general, and you should almost certainly reconsider your design to avoid requiring that knowledge.

Comment: Skeel: I'll explain in the post.

Comment: @JuninZe: What about other operators apart from `Where`? It's not really clear what you mean by a "QueryBase" here - it feels like there's a lot of context we're missing, but it *may* not all be relevant. It's not clear to me at all at the moment what it means to "redo" a QueryBase, or what effect the filter would have on it...

Answer (score 2):

The IQueryable side of Linq runs on Expressions. Expressions are an object-based tree structure more or less representing all the operations you could perform on a Queryable. This allows for "code as data", allowing code to dynamically build other code that can then be evaluated either as a structure to build something else, like SQL, or compiled and run to produce a result within the runtime.

In your specific case, you would traverse this expression tree, top to bottom, left to right, looking for a node of type `MethodCallExpression` (or that has a NodeType of `ExpressionType.Call`), referencing a MethodInfo describing a method named "System.Linq.Queryable.Where`2".

Now, as Jon Skeet and others have said, this is brittle. First, you have to implement an Expression walker that will properly traverse every *other* type of Expression node to make sure you traverse the entire tree to find your Where clause. Second, there can be a Where method that doesn't operate on the "trunk" IQueryable; it may for instance be in a lambda statement operating on a sub-collection:

```
db.Contacts
    .OrderBy(c=>c.PhoneNumbers
                    .Where(pn=>pn.Type == PhoneType.Mobile)
                    .OrderBy(pn=>pn.DateLastCalledSuccessfully)
                    .FirstOrDefault());
```

This is another possible pitfall; the `FirstOrDefault()` (and `LastOrDefault()`) methods have overloads which accept a predicate. They do not necessarily evaluate to a call to the Queryable.Where function. By the same token, the end user could define his own predicate-style methods (`FilterBy()`, `WhereNot()`, etc) either for his own use or to match the querying grammar he intends to show to the end user in his application. Your code, if it looks only for `System.Linq.Queryable.Where()` (or even if it looked for any method named "Where"), would not find these. By the same token, the more you broaden your search, the more methods you find that match the names you'd expect to be used for predicates, but that aren't predicate-based functions.